# Does POSIX mention cc or only c99?

Tags: posix, compiler

I know that the most recent versions of POSIX specify that a C99-compliant compiler should (optionally) be present and called `c99`. Similarly, older versions of POSIX used to specify an optional `c89` command to exist as part of the "C-Language Development Utilities".

However, I'm having a hard time finding any reference to `cc`. Is this command mentioned somewhere in the POSIX standard or just a convention?

Comment: It's leftover from the original C compilers and reluctance to use **`c89`** when the two (cc/c89) were considered to be the same thing.  Finding an authoritative source for that will be hard, since the POSIX documentation eliminates most of the historical information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original POSIX 1003.1 (published in 1988) specified a `cc` utility. The Single Unix Specification version 2 (1997) included both [`cc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/cc.html) and [`c89`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/c89.html). The name `c89` was introduced to be a standard dialect of C. The name `cc` was kept but marked as legacy and declared to be an unspecified dialect of C. Many vendors shipped a compiler that defaulted to [K&R C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C) (i.e. pre-ANSI C) under the name `cc`. You might note that `cc` is mandatory while `c89` is part of the C language development option. It was common to have a C compiler under the name `cc` that was only really capable of compiling kernel drivers, and commercial unices often charged extra for a proper C compiler.

POSIX 1003.1-2001 (Single Unix v3) specifies [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/c99.html) specifies instead of `c89`, to use an updated standard dialect of C. You can see some editorial traces left from a draft that included a `cc` utility as well, but `cc` was removed from the specification. POSIX 1003.1-2008 (Single Unix v4) again just has [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, by removing `cc` they made a C compiler optional as part of the "C-Language Development Utilities" instead of required?

Comment: That's a very good and well-researched answer! I wonder why later versions of POSIX didn't specify `c11` or `c17` - they all seem to have stuck with `c99`.

Comment: (And those "editorial traces" were causing me quite a bit of confusion - thanks for clearing it up.)